# Why does this code have a "EOF in inline file" error and what can I do to fix it?

Tags: c, compilation, eof, crc, pelles-c

I got this source code straight from the manufacturer and I cannot get it to compile. I always get a EOF in file error.

I am using Pelles C to compile on Windows 10 X64. It seems that it should be pretty straight forward but I cant figure it out. It should be a program that I supply a string and it should print a crc

```
int main(){
    str scan = "";
    printf("Enter String");
    fgets(scan, 10, stdin);
    calc_crc_half(scan, 4);
    return(0);
}

INT16U cal_crc_half(INT8U far *pin, INT8U len){
    INT16U crc;
    INT8U da;
    INT8U far *ptr;
    INT8U bCRCHign;
    INT8U bCRCLow;

    INT16U crc_ta[16]={
        0x0000,0x1021,0x2042,0x3063,0x4084,0x50a5,0x60c6,0x70e7,
        0x8108,0x9129,0xa14a,0xb16b,0xc18c,0xd1ad,0xe1ce,0xf1ef
    };
    ptr=pin;
    crc=0;
    while(len--!=0) 
    {
        da=((INT8U)(crc>>8))>>4;
        crc<<=4;
        crc^=crc_ta[da^(*ptr>>4)];
        da=((INT8U)(crc>>8))>>4;
        crc<<=4;
        crc^=crc_ta[da^(*ptr&0x0f)];
        ptr++;
    }
    bCRCLow = crc;
    bCRCHign= (INT8U)(crc>>8);

    if(bCRCLow==0x28||bCRCLow==0x0d||bCRCLow==0x0a){
        bCRCLow++;
    }

    if(bCRCHign==0x28||bCRCHign==0x0d||bCRCHign==0x0a){
        bCRCHign++;
    }
    crc = ((INT16U)bCRCHign)<<8;
    crc += bCRCLow;
    printf(crc);
    return(crc);
}
```

I expect the output to be a four character string.

Comment: This code doesn't open or read a file. You need to post the code that is generating the error.

Comment: This is the code i got from the manufacturer, i just formatted it so that its easier to read. I get the error when I try to compile it with "pomake.exe makefile" .

Comment: Forgive me, but you realize that this is not an executable program? This is the code for a function. You do have an executable program with a `main` function, right?

Comment: I added a main() function. I'll update the original post.

Comment: Is `printf()` in this environment a different function than the standard one? I'd expect it to not compile because of that at the very least...

Comment: printf() should be standard in my environment. I installed pelles-C and tried to compile. I made no changes to my environment.

Comment: I removed the printf() line and I still get the error while compiling

Comment: Also, what's the exact error message?

Comment: And what is this `str` type? How can it work with `fgets()`, which expects a char array with at least 10 elements the way you're using it?

Comment: The error says "Fatal Error: Unexpected EOF in inline file". C is not a language I am very familiar with. I just threw the main() function together real quick, I just want it to compile so I can get my CRC's

Comment: What headers do you include?  Did you write any of them?  The term 'inline file' is unusual; I don't think it has a standard meaning, so it may be a term used only by your Pelles compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that you got this code "straight from the manufacturer", presumably you need the CRC's generated using this specific implementation for a particular purpose. This code will work. If you can't get it to compile, you're not doing something correctly in the Pelles C IDE. If that's the case, you might try using a wizard to generate a simple "Hello World" program, and when you get it to compile and run, replace that code with this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned short cal_crc_half(unsigned char *pin, size_t len){
  unsigned short crc;
  unsigned char da;
  unsigned char *ptr;
  unsigned char bCRCHign;
  unsigned char bCRCLow;

  unsigned short crc_ta[16]={
    0x0000,0x1021,0x2042,0x3063,0x4084,0x50a5,0x60c6,0x70e7,
    0x8108,0x9129,0xa14a,0xb16b,0xc18c,0xd1ad,0xe1ce,0xf1ef
  };
  ptr=pin;
  crc=0;
  while(len--!=0) 
  {
    da=((unsigned char)(crc>>8))>>4;
    crc<<=4;
    crc^=crc_ta[da^(*ptr>>4)];
    da=((unsigned char)(crc>>8))>>4;
    crc<<=4;
    crc^=crc_ta[da^(*ptr&0x0f)];
    ptr++;
  }
  bCRCLow = (unsigned char)crc;
  bCRCHign= (unsigned char)(crc>>8);

  if(bCRCLow==0x28||bCRCLow==0x0d||bCRCLow==0x0a){
    bCRCLow++;
  }

  if(bCRCHign==0x28||bCRCHign==0x0d||bCRCHign==0x0a){
    bCRCHign++;
  }
  crc = ((unsigned short)bCRCHign)<<8;
  crc += bCRCLow;
  return crc;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char word[256];
  unsigned short crc;
  puts("Type each word and hit 'Enter'. Enter 'quit' to exit.\n");
  while (fgets(word, 256, stdin) != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(word, "quit\n") == 0) break;
    crc = cal_crc_half(word, strcspn(word, "\n"));
    printf("%X\n", crc);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for `da=((unsigned char)(crc>>8))>>4;
    crc<<=4;` vs. `da = (crc >> 8) & 0xF0;`?  Oh, I see that's what OP was doing.

Comment: Suggest `cal_crc_half(unsigned char *pin, size_t len)` --> `cal_crc_half(const unsigned char *pin, size_t len)`

Comment: @chux: The only changes I made to OP's CRC implementation were a couple of type-casts to eliminate compiler warnings, and to eliminate the header-defined types in favor of native types. Good catch on stripping the newline from input, though. Can't believe I forgot to do that.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thank You for your response. Your code works perfectly. I can now calculate the CRC's for my serial commands for my solar charge controller. Incase anyone else needs it, this is the CRC source code for the MPP Solar LV2424.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Is it possible to convert this to python code? I've been learning to code, but I am used to scripting languages like Javascript and Python, I just don't know enough to know whether or not I can implement this into python.

Comment: @TimYorba: I assume it's possible, but not being experienced in Python, I couldn't begin to tell you how to do it. If you are familiar with Python, go ahead and try. What's the worst that could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Code lacks a proper buffer for reading.  Attempting to write to the string literal `"""` is *undefined behavior* (UB).  [@Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427513/why-does-this-code-have-a-eof-in-inline-file-error-and-what-can-i-do-to-fix-it/55431924#comment97574385_55427513)

```
int main() {
  // str scan = ""; 
  char scan[11];
  printf("Enter String");
  fgets(scan, 10, stdin);
  calc_crc_half(scan, 4);
```

The code will calculate the CRC based on input potentially including the `'\n'`.

---

I expect OP needs a front end more like

```
int main(void) {
  char scan[100];  // be more generous in input possibilities.
  printf("Enter String\n");
  if (fgets(scan, sizeof scan, stdin)) {
    scan[strcspn(scan, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential \n
    calc_crc_half(scan, strlen(scan));
  }
```